Transform crypt() from PHP to Node.js
I'm having a problem converting crypt() from PHP to Node.js
I have a database with the reg_users table where I have columns like username and password.
In PHP, it's very simple to encrypt the password in the login system. I receive the raw password from the post and transform it with crypt into a hash:
$user = isset($dado["username"]) ? $dado["username"] : null;
$pass = isset($dado["password"]) ? $dado["password"] : null;
$password = crypt($pass, '$6$rounds=20000$xtreamcodes$');

When admin is typed, the following hash appears:
$6$rounds=20000$xtreamcodes$XThC5OwfuS0YwS4ahiifzF14vkGbGsFF1w7ETL4sRRC5sOrAWCjWvQJDromZUQoQuwbAXAFdX3h3Cp3vqulpS0

I want to replicate this in node.js, but I can't.
In node I'm doing this:
async function verificaSenha(password){
    var options = {
        cost: 10,
        salt: "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxc"
     }
     
     var hash = Password.hash(password, "PASSWORD_DEFAULT", options);
    console.log(hash);
}

// Endpoint para login
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await RegUser.findOne({ where: { username } });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Usuário ou senha incorretos' });
        }

        // Verificar a senha fornecida com o hash armazenado
        const isPasswordValid = verificaSenha(password);

        if (!isPasswordValid) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Usuário ou senha incorretos' });
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id, username: user.username }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
        res.json({ message: 'Login bem-sucedido', token, success: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao realizar login:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro no servidor' });
    }
});


"can't" because...? What have you tried? What was the problem you had? Please provide a [mre] of your issue. See also [ask]

I just added more information

Ok. We can see the nodeJS code now. So what's the result of it, exactly? Bear in mind that, as documented, crypt() uses DES to generate the hash, but I'm not sure it's clear what the Password.hash function you've used in nodeJS uses, or exactly what it does. Did you get that function from a specific library? If so please inform us and provide a link to the relevant documentation.

I used a library from github
const Password = require("node-php-password");
https://github.com/thomas-alrek/node-php-password

That library is for emulating password_hash(), not crypt(). They're not the same thing.

Do you know of any library that emulates exactly what crypt() does?

As per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php, password_verify in PHP can verify passwords created using PHP's crypt(). Therefore if that library emulates PHP's password functions in full, Password.verify in the nodeJS library should also be able to verify passwords generated using PHP's crypt(). It's worth trying it out before you look for anything else.

And because your nodeJS code is supposed to be checking passwords rather than generating them, it should always have been using Password.verify instead of Password.hash anyway - see also https://github.com/thomas-alrek/node-php-password?tab=readme-ov-file#to-verify-a-password-against-an-existing-hash-in-a-database-ol) Password.hash / password_hash() is only used to generate a new password, not to check an existing one.

The only way I was able to make verification possible was by creating a function to convert the password using a PHP script.
async function convertPass(pass) {
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost/pass.php';
    const params = { pass: pass };

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, { params: params });
        
        return response.data; 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao fazer a requisição:', error);
        throw error; 
    }
}

I call it this way in the API:
// Endpoint para login
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await RegUser.findOne({ where: { username } });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Usuário ou senha incorretos' });
        }

        // Verificar a senha fornecida com o hash armazenado
        const isPasswordValid = await convertPass(password);
        
        if (isPasswordValid != user.password) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Usuário ou senha incorretos' });
        }

        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id, username: user.username }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
        res.json({ message: 'Login bem-sucedido', token, success: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Erro ao realizar login:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Erro no servidor' });
    }
});

The php file:
<?php
$pass = isset($_GET['pass']) ? $_GET['pass'] : null;

$password = crypt($pass, '$6$rounds=20000$xtreamcodes$');

echo $password;
?>

It's not a completely correct way but it's working.

This does not look secure. The hashed password should not be exposed on an endpoint from your PHP app like that. Did you try using Password.verify, as I suggested above?
